# Overheating/insulation destruction of Transformers

Tags: transformer

Let's say you have a very critical circuit (for example special GFCI, hospital emergency equipment, airplane wing motors, etc.) that shouldn't allow the transformer fuse/breaker to nuisance trip. So you don't use any fuse/breaker, not even slow blow or thermal fuse at all.

If there is accidental shorting that can overheat and destroy the transformer insulation. Would the winding just explode? Or would the transformer caught fire? Or perhaps the core itself blowing up into smithereens?

What have you actually witnessed?

This is for small 1000va transformer and below. And not those power lines transformer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a transformer overheats through overcurrent, the copper windings heat first. Eventually, the wire will reach a temperature at which the insulation begins to degrade, to lose mechanical strength, to smoke and char, to catch fire, to melt (not necessarily in that order).

If the heating occurs very slowly, say a 1.5x rated current overload, which will eventually give a 2.25x rated temperature rise, then the transformer iron will be at a similar temperature. A temperature sensor, or cutout switch, mounted on the transformer iron, would be able to trip, and disconnect the power, without the windings being much hotter than the switch.

If the heating occurs rapidly, say the 20x current you might get from shorting a transformer, which will give you 400x the power dissipation in the windings, the windings might reach a dangerous temperature for the insulation in seconds. There will be no time for the core to heat from the windings, so a thermal switch on the transformer would be useless. Fortunately a current of this magnitude will easily blow a fuse.

This difference leads to the standard method of protecting a transformer against all overload scenarios, a fuse of 2 or 3 times the rated current to protect from short circuits, time delay so it doesn't nuisance break on transients, plus a thermal switch mounted on the transformer to disconnect on lower overloads. The thermal switch will also protect against high ambient temperatures pushing the transformer temperature up as well, should cooling fail for some reason.

> What have you actually witnessed?

A long time ago I used a (quite expensive) signal generator from a well-known manufacturer. Internally, the power supply was 'crowbar' protected against over-voltage. If the over-voltage detector tripped, it was designed to trigger an SCR directly across the power supply output, to blow the primary instrument fuse. Unfortunately there was too much residual resistance in the circuit (or maybe somebody had replaced the fuse with a higher rating (don't do that)) and the fuse didn't blow. The transformer cooked, boiled off insulation, and condensed grot coated every surface and switch contact within the instrument, rendering it beyond economic repair. We noticed the plume of smoke and unplugged quickly, averting a likely fire.

Comment: If you use fast fuse 10 times the rated current. It won't nuisance break anymore on transients? But can still trip on pure short, isn't it?  My 100VA autotransformer arrived. My maximum load is only less than 10VA (100% sure). If I put fast fuse (say I don't want to use slow fuse because no available). I don't want it to nuisance trip on transient so maybe 10A fuse would be ok?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use an over-rated fast fuse. It's a much better idea to use a closer rated time delay fuse. You are at liberty however to do whatever you want. You are not at liberty to say you did the wrong thing without being advised it was a bad idea. Use a time delay fuse. There are also ways to 'soft start' a transformer to reduce nuisance transients.

Comment: Usually what is the amplitude of transients, how high can it reach compared to the transformer rated current?

Comment: It can be as big as the short circuit current, and can takes tens of mains cycles to tail-off. The bigger the transformer, the larger the transient. The worst case is when it's switched on at zero voltage. In the first quarter cycle, the flux rises from zero to maximum, in the next quarter cycle the core saturates, inductance stops limiting the current, and it's only winding resistance that limits it. With low resistance, it can take a long time for the voltage developed by the s/c current times resistance to 'walk' the flux back to non-saturating. Peak-voltage switch-on is best case.

Comment: I'm looking for slow blow 5A fuses at stores. How many milliseconds before the fuse blows, or is it in seconds (are there different time for each brand?)? If it takes too long for the fuses to blow, and the current reaches 20X, won't this damage the winding?

Comment: If you look up the data for any type of fuse, you'll find an I^2t figure that represents its thermal capacity, this gives fusing time for any given large current. Only temperature damages mains transformers, current does not, no matter how big. That's why you use a closely-rated fuse, so it will blow before the transformer overheats. Test your transformer. Measure the primary resistance. S/C the secondary for 1s. Remeasure. Tempco of copper is 0.4%/C, or 10% for 25C rise. S/C again, longer pulses if required, until you measure a total 10% increase in resistance. Overheat takes 3 times longer.

Comment: ok. I ordered just 12 pieces of slow blow 1A and 5A fuses. There are minimum orders. Thanks. Say. You said above current did not damage transformers. Have you experienced shorting of secondary where there is continuous spark before the thermal fuse engages (assuming it has no slow blow fuses)?

Comment: a spark where? A s/c is a solid connection.

Comment: When you short the mains ac direct from the transmission lines in the  power company. You can see sparks before any solid connection is formed. How come it sparks immediately before there is temperature rise in the transmission lines transformers?

Comment: I don't understand your concern with sparks. Sparks heat the air immediately around them, and the conductors they originate on. Transformer windings are heated by current flowing through them. Sparks are totally incidental to fusing and trandformer temp rsie calculations, just as your electricity bill would be incidental to them. I have no clue how you think they are relevant, so am not able to make an appropriate answer to your concern.

Comment: What you said about transformers also applied to big transmission lines transformers? But when we short the two ac lines, the utility pole transformer windings won't heat up before the wires get destroyed. Why is smaller 500va transformer not the same?

Comment: The scale is different, which affects all sorts of things. With high voltage distribution (big transformers) the wires are relatively thin (as you can have with high voltage), so if the breakers fail to operate, the wires toast. Big transformers are more efficient, ie have lower losses, than small transformers, it's just the way the geometry scales. Just design for your 500VA transformer, don't get confused by industrial scale stuff.

Comment: I was referring to the wires of the house connected to the utility pole transformers. When something is shorted, you can see sparks or arcs. What I was asking was have you actually tried shorting secondary of a small 500va transformer? Since I don't wanna try it. I was asking if you can see sparks forming in the shorted region or no sparks? This was all I was asking. Sparks or no sparks, that is the question. Thanks.

Comment: When something is shorted, you don't see sparks. When something is sparking, you see sparks. A good way to make sparks is to disconnect a circuit carrying a large current. Another good way is to have a high voltage across a small gap. None of this has anything to do with overheating transformers.

Comment: Maybe you are using DC in your country? Because in the US. If you short the neutral and hot line or between two hot lines, you will see silvery fireworks in the shorted wire. What do you call them then if they are not called "sparks". I'll search for youtube video of it. I'm surprised you haven't seen one before .

Comment: I think what you might be doing is having a high voltage across a small gap, when you put a wire between hot and neutral, creating a spark. They're pretty to watch, but they're not in the wire. They are between the wires, or instead of the wire. However, if you want to measure the current going through your transformer, then use an ammeter.

Comment: If you connect a straight wire to two terminal of a plug, and you insert the plug in the receptacle. You will see big spark as the wire or terminal gets cut in two. Where does the spark come from?

Comment: The high current heats the wire. Eventually, the wire gets to melting point. Even absent of any stress in the wire, surface tension causes instability in the thickness, and ripples grow until the wire necks down in one part and breaks. At this point a spark develops between the two wire ends. The spark has a higher voltage drop across it than the wire, so heats the wire ends rapidly, boiling the metal and creating a plasma, which maintains a conducting channel for the spark to continue to pass. The heat continues to erode the wire ends. None of which has anything to do with transformer heating

Comment: Ok. Thanks. So the key word is "melting point", not sparks. In ac supply. When you short something, the high current heats the wire and it gets to melting point very fast, almost within one second. Were you saying that in 500v transformer. It would take more seconds for this to occur? What's the longest have you tried before the current melts and narrows down the wire?

Comment: If you're interested in your transformer survival time, why not measure the I^2t? Then you can compare it with the values that fuses are designed to protect. The difference is the length of wire that's in the transformer, meaning a much lower s/c current flows in the transformer than in a bit of wire across a plug. If you had 100s of metres of wire between your plug pins (that is, the length of wire in your transfomer), that would survive a long time.

Comment: The bit of wire across your plug, that has an I^2t rating to failure, failure being its melting point. Your transformer has an I^2t rating, but only to perhaps 100C temperature rise, above which the insulation becomes damaged. The difference in s/c current is down to the length of wire that the mains voltage is across.

Comment: In your experience, how many ampere before any two nearby terminals in a home panel can develop into arc flash.. like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hpE5LYj-CY and can AFCI totally prevent it or just make the intensity lesser?

Comment: AFCIs are new to me. Presumably they analyse the waveform, and trip if the 'signature' of an arc is detected. These will not trip if your transformer is overheating due to a non-arcing s/c, but may do if it is. If you're asking what's th eminimum current I can break and still form an arc, I've done that with less than 1 amp.

Comment: In the UK. Can dropping a tool between say the 240v hot and neutral in the bus bar in the main panel able to produce arc flash? Or can't it sustain it? If not.. why can't it sustain it?